# How to get all results with cts:search?

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I am using cts:search like this:-

```
let $query :=
         cts:or-query((
            cts:field-word-query(
              "Assignor Name", $assignorName
            ), 
            cts:field-word-query(
              "Assignee Name", $assigneeName
            )
        )) 
for $patent in cts:search(fn:doc(), $query)[1 to 10]
return $patent
```

where $assignorName and $assigneeName is the input from the user. But when both $assignorName & $assigneeName are empty strings then it does not show any results.  I want to show all the results when the user does not enter any input.  How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 4):

More explicitly, you might write the query something like this:

```
    cts:or-query((
        if (not($assignorName)) then () else cts:field-word-query(
          "Assignor Name", $assignorName), 
        if (not($assigneeName)) then () else cts:field-word-query(
          "Assignee Name", $assigneeName) ))
```

It takes a while to get used to the idea that you can put an `if-then-else` expression practically anywhere. Sometimes it helps to think of it as ternary logic.

Answer (score 1):

To get all results, you have to replace the current `$query` with `cts:and-query(())`. A `cts:or-query(())` might work too by the way.

HTH!